# Can not set a state in a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a react component. I want to set the state within this component that will be passed down to child components. I am getting a reference error to this and I am not sure why.

```
export const WidgetToolbar: React.FC<{}> = () => {

    this.state = {
        targetBox:null,
    }

    const isOpen = useBehavior(mainStore.isWidgetToolbarOpen);
    const themeClass = useBehavior(mainStore.themeClass);

    const userDashboards = useBehavior(dashboardStore.userDashboards);

    const [filter, setFilter] = useState("");
    const [sortOrder, setSortOrder] = useState<SortOrder>("asc");

    const userWidgets = useMemo(() => {
        let _userWidgets = values(userDashboards.widgets).filter((w) => w.widget.isVisible);

        if (sortOrder === "asc") {
            _userWidgets.sort((a, b) => a.widget.title.localeCompare(b.widget.title));
        } else {
            _userWidgets.sort((a, b) => b.widget.title.localeCompare(a.widget.title));
        }
        if (!isBlank(filter)) {
            _userWidgets = _userWidgets.filter((row) => {
                return row.widget.title.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLocaleLowerCase());
            });
        }
        return _userWidgets;
    }, [userDashboards, sortOrder, filter]);
    ...
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'state' of undefined
    at WidgetToolbar (WidgetToolbar.tsx?ba4c:25)
    at ProxyFacade (react-hot-loader.development.js?439b:757)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no `this` or `this.state` in a functional component. Use the useState hook, similar to what you're doing a few lines below.

```
export const WidgetToolbar: React.FC<{}> = () => {
    const [targetBox, setTargetBox] = useState<null | whateverTheTypeIs>(null);

    //...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Functional React Components can't have state. You'd have to use a class-based component in order to have state.

https://guide.freecodecamp.org/react-native/functional-vs-class-components/

You used the hook to "use state" in this function: `const [filter, setFilter] = useState("");`

You could do the same for `targetBox`, instead of trying to set a property on a non-existent 'this'

Comment: FWIW this is only true before React 16.8, with the introduction of [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) you can have state in Function components :)

Comment: Using the hook setState, is not the same as having state management. It's more like a state variable https://codeburst.io/quick-intro-to-react-hooks-6dd8ecb898ed

Comment: I'd say the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) would suggest the contrary, given `useState` can be used in place of `this.state` / `this.setState` calls, and state is preserved between renders.

Comment: @James It's definitely effectively the same, so there's no point splitting hairs. I was under the impression it behaved a bit differently under the hood but I think I was mistaken: https://overreacted.io/how-does-setstate-know-what-to-do/

Comment: yeah, I'm sure I read Dan Abramov explain that it's much closer to how React works behind the scenes.